# The unmatched function signature between function objects in c++

Tags: c++

I got this code piece as below, and it builds:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(int)> ReadCallback;

void falseRead() {}

int main()
{
    ReadCallback callback = std::bind(falseRead);
}
```

The signature of ReadCallback is `void(int)`, whereas the signature of falseRead is `void()`. How can the assignment happen?

And if I use the `callback` object to call the function, which statement should I use, `callback()` or `callback(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind-expression is callable with any number of arguments; arguments that don't correspond to placeholders are discarded.

```
auto f = std::bind(falseRead);

f(a, b, c);  // equivalent to falseRead();
```

Therefore, your bind-expression can be used to construct an `std::function<void(int)>` object:

```
std::function<void(int)> g = f;

g(a);  // = f(a) = falseRead()
```

It's the opposite direction that's forbidden: If your bound function takes parameters, you must provide values for the arguments (either bound values or placeholders):

```
void realRead(int fd, char* buf);

auto h = std::bind(realRead, _1, buf);  // h(fd) = realRead(fd, buf)
// auto h = std::bind(realRead);        // error
```